# Describe the equivalence relation of the following set with the given partition.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Describe the equivalence relation of the following set with the given partition.

> $ \Bbb N $ , $ \{\{ 1 \}, \{2,3 \}, \{4,5,6,7\},\{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}....\} . $

What this question has me confused about is what  it wants me to accomplish. Am I supposed to make an equation from this set and analyze if it is reflexive,symmetric, or transitive? Then the part of the partition also throws me off. I know that $p$ is partition of $a$ iff $p$ is a set of subsets of $a$. What I am looking for in this question is a hint in the right direction so that I may produce an answer. I also know that the sets here are restricted so that it must be greater than $0$. Or $\left(x \;\text{ and }\; y \right)$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$. Any hints on how to proceed would be good.

**edit**

Def: Let  A be nonempty set $. \mathscr P$ is  partition of A iff $. \mathscr P$ is a set of subsets of A such that

$(i) \quad \text{If } X \in \mathscr P, \text{then} \; x\not = \varnothing $

$(ii)\; If  \;x\in \mathscr P \; \text{and} \; y \in \mathscr P, \text{then } x=y  \text{ or } x \cap y = \varnothing$

$(iii) \; \cup_{x \in \mathscr P} X = A$

Comment: A partition is not only a set of subsets, but those subsets have to be pairwise disjoint and their union has to be the base set again: Given a partition $P = \{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ of a set $S$ we know that $P_i \cap P_j = \emptyset \forall i \neq j$ and $\bigcup_{i\in I} P_i = S$.

Then we define the cannonical equivalence relation for $a,b \in S$: $a ~ b :\iff \exists i \in I \text{ s.t. } a\in P_i, b\in P_i$.

Comment: The relation induced by a partition will always be an equivalence relation; you don't have to prove that. The question is to characterize the equivalence classes, and figure out a (first-order) formula $\varphi(x,y)$  such that $\varphi(x,y)$ holds *iff* $x, y$ are in the same equivalence class. What can you say about $\log_2(x)$ and $\log_2(y)$ if $x,y$ are, or aren't, in the same equivalence class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition of a set $X$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ such that union of all these subsets gives $X$. Any partition naturally sets an equivalence relation and vise versa. The partition in your question can be set by equivalence relation that can be described in many ways. For example like this: we say that $x$ is equivalent to $y$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same number of digits in binary representation. Check, that this an equivalence relation and that classes of equivalence form exactly your partition.

Comment: So for this question, would a good educated guess about determining what the equation is. xRy = $\{ 2^n + 1 ..... \}  n \in \Bbb N$ ?

Comment: Because $ 2^0 = 1, 2^{1} = 2$ and so on

Comment: @LittleJon, I don't understand your question. Your relation can be described as $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same number of digits in binary representation. Another way, as BrianO suggested, is via formula with logarithms, e.g. $\log_2(x)-\log_2(y)<1$

Comment: Why do we need to use logarithms in this problem?

Comment: You need the *floor* of $\log_2$: given integers $x,y$, $xRy$ *iff* the highest power of $2$ that's $\le x$ equals the highest power of $2$ that's $\le y$. The sets in the partition are:
$$
P_n = \{2^n + i \mid 0 \le i < 2^n\}.
$$
You don't need analysis to talk about it, the language of arithmetic is enough.

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand so if it meets one of the certain conditions above then it is a partition.